# geom_smooth only displays one confidence interval, or one of them is weird

Tags: ggplot2, linear-regression

I am trying to plot trends over time, with two different variables of interest. Everything works well, but if I am trying to plot trendline and confidence interval, I run into problems. Either one of the confidence intervals / error shadings is missing (with method = "glm") or one of them is displayed very weird.
My data is (first number is prevalance, second SE):

```
1   2012    Meditation                  8.89    0.2495712
2   2012    Relaxation                  5.43    0.1767925
3   2017    Meditation                  12.41   0.3116123
4   2017    Relaxation                  7.69    0.2257649
5   2022    Meditation                  14.40   0.3050083
6   2022    Relaxation                  9.87    0.2460135
```

I am trying to use the following code:

### plotting all the trends over 20 years

```
ggplot(trends_df, aes(x=Year, y=Percentages, group=Practice, colour=Practice)) +
    geom_line(size=1, position = position_dodge(0.1)) + 
    geom_label(aes(label=Percentages), colour="white", fill="white", label.size = NA, key_glyph = "point") +
    geom_text(aes(label=Percentages), size=3, key_glyph = "point", check_overlap = TRUE) +
    scale_colour_manual(name = element_blank(),
                      limits = c("Meditation", "Relaxation"), 
                      values = c("#99cc99",     
                                 "#999999"),
                      labels = c("Meditation", "Relaxation")) +
    geom_smooth(data=trends_df, method = "glm", formula = y ~ x, aes(fill = Practice), show.legend = FALSE, se = TRUE) +
    scale_fill_manual(limits = c("Meditation", "Relaxation"),          
                       values=c("#99cc99","#999999"))+
    ylim(0, 20) +
    ylab("Percentages of Practitioners") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2010, 2024), breaks = c(2012, 2017, 2022)) +
    theme_classic()+
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'), 
          legend.position = "bottom",
          #legend.key = element_rect(color = trends_df$Practice),
          legend.key.height = unit(0.5, 'cm'), 
          legend.key.width = unit(0.5, 'cm'), 
          legend.title = element_text(size=16), 
          legend.text = element_text(size=14),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

which gives me the following:[glm plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6pFG.png)

OR if I am running the same code, but with:

```
 geom_smooth(data=trends_df, method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(fill = Practice), show.legend = FALSE, se = TRUE)
```

I get the following: [lm plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrApu.png)

My best solution so far is simply add two lines, one geom_smooth, one stat_smooth, with the two different methods (lm and glm) and another dataframe for lm as input, where the data for green (Meditation) is deleted. But I am not sure if it is correct to do so... Has anyone a better idea? Or does anyone know what is happening here??

Thank you!